# Managing 1 million records per month insert/select

Tags: mongodb, scalability

I am working on a real time feed which gives me real time data.
The Number of records are up to **1 million per month** and I need to provide reports based on these records.

I chose `Mongodb` as it is high performer in fetching records.

I am facing issue in managing that data because **12 million records**.
Do I need to keep every data month wise?
Should I use different collections per month?

There are lot of select queries for Analytics Report and everything.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but that sounds pretty vague for anyone to give suggestions. You're not even providing any details about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to use the data, that's up to you to decide. There is nothing wrong with a lot of data, you just need to limit your heavy queries with the same logic as cache works (easier access, but less fresh). A common methods is:

You have a "raw data" table which contains your millions of records. This table is very large, but contains 'pure' data. You want to access this table as little as possible as it'll be slow.

The next table is less accurrate and sums information you need. In your case this could be a 'month_summery' which you create after a month ends. That way you still have the complete dataset, but also a small table with relevent info (e.g. num lines, sumOfX, averageOfY, etc). Your heavy query is now once per month and you can base your stats of this.

If you need data say per week, you'd make a 'week_summery' table. Or if you need stats per day, you make it per day, 365 entries per year is still a whole lot less than millions.